# Decode unfamiliar JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json

How do I decode this strange JSON into an object? What is this format?

```
{&q;tealium&q;:&q;dev&q;,&q;user&q;:{&q;data&q;:{&q;challenge&q;:{&q;mobile&q;:&q;*******444&q;,&q;email&q;:&q;t****@t****.io&q;,&q;sendTo&q;:&q;Mobile&q;},&q;username&q;:&q;9355045176762&q;,&q;state&q;:&q;6f23c898-d29e-4aa7-a5aa-2251c998fabd&q;,&q;otptoken&q;:&q;YG0VB2VZRiY3a69VdGOzLAEj2JUc&q;}},&q;requestData&q;:{&q;emailCardNumber&q;:&q;9355045176762&q;,&q;stateVal&q;:&q;6f23c898-d29e-4aa7-a5aa-2251c998fabd&q;,&q;referrer&q;:&q;rewardsdev_ios&q;}}
```

I came embedded in an HTML document like this:

```
<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">{&q;tealium&q;:&q;dev&q;,&q;user&q;:{&q;data&q;:{&q;challenge&q;:{&q;mobile&q;:&q;*******444&q;,&q;email&q;:&q;t****@t****.io&q;,&q;sendTo&q;:&q;Mobile&q;},&q;username&q;:&q;9355045176762&q;,&q;state&q;:&q;2a3da8cb-3369-4b0f-9da6-633b49786027&q;,&q;otptoken&q;:&q;p1wlBP6Giv8P4outSAdnwP6ACcH4&q;}},&q;requestData&q;:{&q;emailCardNumber&q;:&q;9355045176762&q;,&q;stateVal&q;:&q;2a3da8cb-3369-4b0f-9da6-633b49786027&q;,&q;referrer&q;:&q;rewardsdev_ios&q;}}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clean it up with a regex:

```
s = s.replace(/&q;/g, '"');
JSON.parse(s); // valid object
```